# how to build a new variable based on another variable's percentile

Tags: r

If I have a var `score` in `df` that is the score of a test. I would like to build a new var `Score1` base on the score percentile. how should I build it. For example: if score is in top 25%, then  `Score1`=1, if top 50%, then 2; 75%, then 3, 75-100% , 4. `Score1` is based on Score, and divide df into 4 cats. It is not randomized

Is there a way to split data  or build this new variable easily?

what if later I just want to split data into 4 cats randomly. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: The random would be `df$cat <- sample(1:4, size=length(df$value), replace=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I like to do it if the groups are small enough. I use nested ifelse statements and then define it as an ordered factor.

```
df<-data.frame(percentile=c(1,20,80,35,50,55,60,60,95,20,30,58,15))
df$group<-ifelse(test=df$percentile>=75,yes = "Score1",
             no = ifelse(test = df$percentile>=50,yes = "Score2",
                    no = ifelse(test = df$percentile>=25,yes = "Score3",
                                no = "Score4")))
df$group<-factor(df$group,levels = c("Score4","Score3","Score2","Score1"),ordered = T)
df

#split into groups
df_Score1<-df[which(df$group=="Score1"),]
df_Score2<-df[which(df$group=="Score2"),]
df_Score3<-df[which(df$group=="Score3"),]
df_Score4<-df[which(df$group=="Score4"),]
```